# Compare objects in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I check if two JavaScript values are the same?

If they are objects, I would like to compare them key-by-key recursively.

I'm looking for an existing function, not a way to write my own like described in this question: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript).

Answer (score 5):

There's a function called [`deepDiffer`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/differ/deepDiffer.js) which does this.

Comment: Haha OK someone didn't like that answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Took a bit of Googling to find how to import `deepDiffer`.

```
import deepDiffer from 'react-native/lib/deepDiffer'

...

deepDiffer(obj1, obj2) // true or false
```

Answer (score 2):

In react native >= 0.62.2 use,

```
import deepDiffer from `react-native/libraries/utilities/differ/deepDiffer`

deepDiffer(obj1, obj2) // true or false
```